# How to set default group permissions for SFTP uploads?

Tags: permissions, sftp

I am connecting to a web server running Debian. Our team uses Apache and all users are members of the www-data group. When we connect to this server via SFTP (e.g. Transmit), all of our newly uploaded files take on a group name that is the same as the user's name (i.e. their primary group).

Is there a way to change this default group assignment to www-data on SFTP? On the command line, one can type:

$ newgrp www-data

Which assigns the current user's primary group to www-data. All new files created by the user are assigned to this group. Is there an equivalent for SFTP?

Comment: See here: http://serverfault.com/questions/150726

Answer (score 15):

Setting a directory setgid means that files created within it will acquire the directory's group ownership.

```
mkdir web
chgrp www-data web
chmod g+s web
```

Answer (score 4):

You may require the additional step of setting the umask before the server process starts:

```
umask 0002;
/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Or in sshd_config, "you can pass a flag and value in (-u 0002) like the following to set the umask value:"

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 0002
```

Comment: This is not reddit. Please don't post links without adding the contained information here, too. If that page is deleted...

Comment: And unfortunately that link is now dead